# How to Interpret Autocorrelation Plot of Residuals

Tags: arima, autocorrelation, residuals

I have a model that is giving me the below autocorrelation plot of residuals.  I'm not sure how to interpret it since it seems somewhat in the middle.

[image: ACF Residuals]

The correlation drops quickly, but it doesn't look much like the chart I found in this [article](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/5/4).  Since it seems to be in the middle should I do another test on it?  Or do you think it drops sharp enough to not have to worry about autocorrelation?

Comment: It looks like daily data which can be quite impacted not only by memory (arima structure) but deterministic structure like day-of-the-week effects , holiday effects , weekly/monthly effects, level shifts , local time trends , pulses etc,. Consider searching for "user 3382 DAILY DATA"